# RoR REST PUT unable to read params on URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Here is my  put REST route:

```
    app.put '/users/:id' do
    content_type "application/json"

    params = JSON.parse(request.body.read)

    reqUserID = params[:id]
    puts params[:id]
    puts reqUserID
```

The browser link I use to check is

```
localhost:3000/users/71?access_token=elwu54j7ef0dxns2gwt072pfwpuxney
```

and the payload is:

```
    {
  "id" : 71,
    "first": "TU4",
    "last": "TU4",
    "email": "TU@cs.com",
    "username": "TU358kkll",
    "bio": "User, student",
  "password":"Test12#"
}
```

My doubts:
1. Do I need to have the id field in the JSON payload?
2. With the above code, I can't display the params[:id]. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!